# How to change the title text of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to add VS extension that will change the title bar text. I found the tools, but I need it in my extension.

I tried:

```
var dte = GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
if(!(dte is null))
    dte.MainWindow.Caption = "Name";
```

but it doesn't work.

Similarly,

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string lpString);

var proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
SetWindowText(proc.MainWindowHandle, "Name);
```

just changes the `Process.MainWindowTitle`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe the extension is in its own process, so you'd first need to find the VS2017 process that is running, then get the handle and run `SetWindowText`.

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv");
foreach(var process in processes)
{
    SetWindowText(process.MainWindowHandle, "Name");
}
```

BIG NOTE:

As a developer please don't mess with my title bars in Visual Studio. I often use these as references between work projects and reference projects when refactoring and various other tasks.

Comment: actually, it doing the same as `var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();`